# go build events undefined

Tags: twitter, elasticsearch, go, logstash

Environment: Windows 10 Professional 64-Bit.

I want to build / install a go-project (twitterbeat as you can see).

```
C:\apps\Go_workspace\src\github.com\buehler\twitterbeat>go build
# github.com/buehler/twitterbeat/beater
beater\twitterbeat.go:62: b.Events undefined (type *beat.Beat has no field or method Events)
```

Here you can see line 62 of the file:

```
func (bt *Twitterbeat) Setup(b *beat.Beat) error {
    logp.Info("Setup waitduration and api keys")

    bt.events = b.Events

    var err error
    bt.period, err = time.ParseDuration(*bt.beatConfig.Period)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    anaconda.SetConsumerKey(*bt.beatConfig.Twitter.ConsumerKey)
    anaconda.SetConsumerSecret(*bt.beatConfig.Twitter.ConsumerSecret)
    bt.api = anaconda.NewTwitterApi(*bt.beatConfig.Twitter.AccessKey, *bt.beatConfig.Twitter.AccessSecret)

    return nil
}
```

I don't think that the code is wrong, because I donwloaded it directly from [Github](https://github.com/buehler/twitterbeat).

Because I am not on a linux / unix system (and I had problems with the proxy), i couldn't run "glide". Instead I donwloaded all dependencies by myself.

What can I do to build twitterbeat?

Comment: glide works on non linux/unix systems, is there a reason you avoided it?

Comment: @matt.s Yes, I know that it works. But our proxy doesn't allow glide, or there's a problem with it. I'm not avoiding linux/unix, I don't have access to linux/unix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you download the dependencies by hand, you need to make sure that they are the same version as in the glide.yaml file.  The current version of `beat.Beat` in `github.com/elastic/libbeat/beat/beat.go` is newer than the one in the glide.yaml and doesn't have an `Events` field any more.

Comment: How can I get the version of beat.go?

Comment: In the `github.com/elastic/beats` directory you need to do a git checkout of the version in the glide.yaml file.  You can put that entire directory in the vendor folder of `buehler/twitterbeat` to make sure the version doesn't update, since that is the same thing that glide does.

Comment: And what do I have to do afterwards? I did the part with checkout the old version..

Comment: The version of `elastic/beats/libbeat/beat.go` should have the Events field in the Beat struct.  If you did the git checkout of `github.com/elastic/beats` of version `ae30528774fffa5879392388f651286785118d38` then you should be able to do `go build` in `buehler/twitterbeat`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not your problem,but a fault of the library you are using.

As the code shows,it used `github.com/elastic/beats/libbeat/beat`,then we jump to the source of `beat`,the `Beat` struct is:

```
type Beat struct {
    Name      string               // Beat name.
    Version   string               // Beat version number. Defaults to the libbeat version when an implementation does not set a version.
    UUID      uuid.UUID            // ID assigned to a Beat instance.
    BT        Beater               // Beater implementation.
    RawConfig *common.Config       // Raw config that can be unpacked to get Beat specific config data.
    Config    BeatConfig           // Common Beat configuration data.
    Publisher *publisher.Publisher // Publisher

    filters *filter.FilterList // Filters
}
```

It doesn't have `Events` field anymore!

You can use the old version of the library  `github.com/elastic/beats/libbeat/beat`,or you can push a issue to the owner of `github.com/buehler/twitterbeat` to inform him to fix this bug.